# OpenLayers 2.12 + click handler + get the name of the vector

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

Basically,

I add several vector layers (KML content got from jQuery GET) in this way:

```
var layer1Vector= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('activeInfo');
layer1Vector.addFeatures(featuresLayer1Vector);
mp.addLayer(layer1Vector);
```

It works quite well.

Instead of adding the

```
selectControlKml = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
    [layer1, layer2, ***], {
        clickout: true, toggle: false,
        multiple: false, hover: false,
        toggleKey: 'ctrlKey',
        multipleKey: 'shiftKey'
    }
);
```

I knew that it's possible to add a "general" click handler event

```
OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
    defaultHandlerOptions:{
        'single': true,
        'double': false,
        'pixelTolerance': 5,
        'stopSingle': true,
        'stopDouble': false,
        'delay': 0
    },  
    initialize: function(options) {
        this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, this.defaultHandlerOptions);
        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments); 
        this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
            this, {'click': this.trigger}, 
            this.handlerOptions
        );
    },
    trigger: function(e) {

        if (e.target._featureId) {
            //var feature = vectorLayer.getFeatureById(e.target._featureId);
            alert('click on fea' + e.target._featureId)
            //$(e.target).css('fill', '#000000');
            //$(e.target).css('cursor', 'wait');
            //$("div#info").append("<span>You just clicked on " + feature.id + "<span><br />");
        }
***
```

If I click on a vector layer I have to open different custom popups (qTip2). The code:

```
if (e.target._featureId) {
```

works, but how can I get the layer name based on the e object? I analyzed all the methods/properties, but without having success.

E.g.
One of my layers was defined as:

```
var layer1Vector= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('activeInfo');
```

I need to get 'activeInfo'.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `this` is the vector in this context... `this.name` will give you "activeInfo".

```js
...
trigger: function(e) {

        alert(this.name);
        if (e.target._featureId) {
...
```

here's my `console.log(this)` within trigger function.

[image]

## UPDATE PER Comment

So [your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/MKdcM/1/) is that you're trying to assign the click handler before the layer has been created.

[This Works. Here](http://jsfiddle.net/MKdcM/3/) I have moved the call to the `addControls(vectorLayer)` function after you add the layer. This works fine. Notice I've added a `layer` parameter. This will make it easy for you when you're adding and removing layers.

Once you remove a vector Layer the handler is gone with it. If you add another layer, simply call the `addControls(yourNewLayerName)` function to add the handler to the new layer.

Comment: No, it's undefined the .name property. It does not exist checking with FF Firebug. Now I'm analyzing the this object.

Comment: Works for me. [Here's my demo test](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/ol/click.html) so you can compare code.

Comment: First of all thanks! The vector layers are loaded dynamically using jQuery. I add the clickHandler function before loading the vectors, probably this could be the reason. I'm doing several tests, I inform you later!

Comment: This is my problem: [Demo test problem](http://jsfiddle.net/MKdcM/1/). I need to update the ClickHandler, but how?

Comment: +Those layers can be removed or re-added, it means I have to update each time the ClickHandler, but how?

Comment: Please see me Update